# ReactJS - values are returned undefined from a function with parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a react app and trying to convert the temperatures that are in Kelvin to Fahrenheit.  I have a simple setup, but I'm getting undefined values from a function.

```
//this is the cityweathercomponent
import React, { Component } from "react";

class CityWeather extends Component {

    // (280.89K − 273.15) × 9/5 + 32

    getFahrenheit = (now, minimum, maximum) => {

        let arr = [now , minimum , maximum];
        let result = [];

        for (let value of arr) {
            let num = (value - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32;
            result.push(num);
        }
        let current = result[0];
        let min = result[1];
        let max = result[2];

        console.log(result);

        return {current, min, max};
    };

    render(){

        let cityID = this.props.city;
        let weatherData = this.props.weatherData;

        let currentWeather = weatherData.list[0];
        let condition = currentWeather.weather[0].main;


        let {temp, minTemp, maxTemp} = this.getFahrenheit(currentWeather.main.temp, currentWeather.main.temp_min, currentWeather.main.temp_max);

        console.log(temp, minTemp, maxTemp);

        return(
            <div>
                <h2>condition</h2>
                <p>{condition}</p>

                <br/>
                <h2>current temp</h2>
                <p>{temp}</p>

                <br/>
                <h2>max temp</h2>
                <p>{maxTemp}</p>
                <br/>
                <h2>min temp</h2>
                <p>{minTemp}</p>
            </div>


        );
    }

}

export default CityWeather;
```

So I'm the temps in `this.getFahrenheit` function, the result it's expected to be in an object with multiple values.

These params are going in that function and being converted in Fahrenheit.  They are stored in an array, and each one is set into variables.  In the end, they are being returned as an object `{current, min, max}`.

But in the console, I'm getting undefined results and not sure what's going on.  I see other examples similar to mine and the results are ok - I'm sure I'm missing something in here.

I'm new to ReactJS and specially ES6, so I would like to understand what's going on here and why they are being set as undefined.  The end goal is to display the new values in the render showing the temp with the right format.  Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: `return {current, min, max};` returns this object: `{ current: current, min: min, max: max}`. You are trying to grab `{temp, minTemp, maxTemp}` but none of those fields exists.

Comment: oh i see, the naming convention needs to be the same in the return `return {current, min, max};` and the output `let {current, min, max}`.  I was wondering why other functions in other answers worked even though they had the same setup.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the following line in your `render` method:

```
let {temp, minTemp, maxTemp} = this.getFahrenheit(currentWeather.main.temp, currentWeather.main.temp_min, currentWeather.main.temp_max);
```

The method `this.getFahrenheit` returns an object with the keys `current`, `min`, and `max`, but the notation `let {temp, minTemp, maxTemp} = this.getFahrenheit(...)` looks for the keys `temp`, `minTemp`, and `maxTemp` in the output of `this.getFahrenheit`. Since these keys are not present in the output, the values of the variables `temp`, `minTemp`, and `maxTemp` all become `undefined`.

You can either use the same variables names as defined in the keys of the output of `this.getFahrenheit` (vars: `current`, `min`, and `max`), like this:

```
let {current, min, max} = this.getFahrenheit(currentWeather.main.temp, currentWeather.main.temp_min, currentWeather.main.temp_max);
```

or you can rename the variables to the ones you are currently using (vars: `temp`, `minTemp`, and `maxTemp`):

```
let {current: temp, min: minTemp, max: maxTemp} = this.getFahrenheit(currentWeather.main.temp, currentWeather.main.temp_min, currentWeather.main.temp_max);
```

See docs for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring